# Unable to call method's objects into the Form

Tags: c#, object, methods, instance, intellisense

As you can see I **instantiated** the classes I need into the **form_load**, in order to use methods and classes features. The problem is that I need to Call the item `NuovoCliente` from `CreateCliente`method, but I don't know how to do, since intellisense, even when I try to type, does not show any link to `NuovoCliente`.

The **class** you can see with the method is `ClienteModel`.
Which is basically structured like this:

```
public class ClienteModel
{
    public int IDCliente { get; set; }
    public string Cognome { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Indirizzo { get; set; }
}
```

This is my **method**, which is placed in `DBMemoryManager` class:

```
public class DBMemoryManager : DBManager
{

    //Array
    ClienteModel[] MemoryClienti = new ClienteModel[0];

    public int CreateCliente(ClienteModel model)
    {
        ClienteModel NuovoCliente = new ClienteModel();
        int MaxCID = MemoryClienti.Select(ClienteModel => ClienteModel.IDCliente).Max();
        MemoryClienti[0] = NuovoCliente;
        NuovoCliente.IDCliente = MaxCID++;

        return NuovoCliente.IDCliente;
    }
```

This is how my **Form** start:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    DBMemoryManager dbMemoryManager = null;
    ClienteModel clienteModel = null;
    OrdineModel ordineModel = null;       

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dbMemoryManager = new DBMemoryManager();
        clienteModel = new ClienteModel();
        ordineModel = new OrdineModel();
    }
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing up class names and variable names. Why are you never using the passed in `model` in `CreateCliente` ? Your question is basically unclear.

Comment: Since you have used `NuovoCliente` inside CreateCliente method you have no reference to that. You can get a `ClienteModel` object (in your case return `NuovoCliente`), if you return the whole object from the CreateCliente methos. (now you are returning a int.)

Comment: Oh sorry, i'll update with my class name. What do you mean why you're not using the passed model? i need to use it in the form, since the application will be improved in future. i don't want to add useless code to methods atm, just use those methods in the form.

Comment: Oh so i should return the entire object? how?

Comment: I don't mean this in a horrible way, but I think you need to start with a beginner guide to writing C#. If returning a value has you confused you're trying to run before you can walk.

Comment: probably.. thanks for the advice..

Comment: public ClienteModel CreateCliente(ClienteModel model) { //rest of the code return NuovoCliente }. This is the method. Return type is ClienteModel. Now call this method in form_load.  dbMemoryManager = new DBMemoryManager(); call dbMemoryManager.CreateCliente(clienteModel ) and you get the NuovoCliente in return. You have access to all properties and variable inside it.

Comment: @DumalAluthdeniya doesn't see to work.. i called dbMemoryManager.CreateCliente(clienteModel) into form_load. I still can't call NuovoCliente...

Comment: did you check my answer. You should get data of your NuovoCliente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return a `ClienteModel` from this method.

```
public ClienteModel CreateCliente(ClienteModel model)
        {
            ClienteModel NuovoCliente = new ClienteModel();
            int MaxCID = MemoryClienti.Select(ClienteModel => ClienteModel.IDCliente).Max();
            MemoryClienti[0] = NuovoCliente;
            NuovoCliente.IDCliente = MaxCID++;
            return NuovoCliente;
        }
```

Now access data from Form_load

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    
    ClienteModel clienteModel = null;
    OrdineModel ordineModel = null;       

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clienteModel = new ClienteModel();
        ordineModel = new OrdineModel();

        DBMemoryManager dbMemoryManager = new DBMemoryManager(); //initialize here
        ClienteModel  nuovoCliente = dbMemoryManager.CreateCliente(clienteModel)
        //here you can get all data from nuovoCliente 
    }
```

here is the data.
[image]

Comment: Doens't seems to work, i still can't call nuovoCliente... my code's exactly like your but i can't call yet.

Comment: No, no compiler's errors without trying to call. If i try to call i get CS1061.

Comment: Initialize DBMemoryManager  before calling the method. Like this(updated my answer ) DBMemoryManager dbMemoryManager = new DBMemoryManager();
I just checked this and it worked fine.

Comment: @paranoidcode Great, Please mark as a correct answer :)